# Does a Javascript Object Destructure assignment use const, let, or var?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In ES6/ES2015 I can use [Object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to pull fields from objects passed as function parameters:

```
function userId({id}) {
  return id;
}

var user = { 
  id: 42, 
};

console.log("userId: " + userId(user)); // "userId: 42"
```

In the above example, is the `id` variable set in the `userId` function equivalent to setting it via `var`, `const`, or `let` ?

So which of the below is the equivalent function:

**Var**

```
function userId(user) {
    var id = user.id
    return id;
}
```

**Let**

```
function userId(user) {
    let id = user.id
    return id;
}
```

**Const**

```
function userId(user) {
    const id = user.id
    return id;
}
```

(Example function from MDN page linked above, jump to "Pulling fields from objects passed as function parameter)

Comment: Well you know it's not `const`, because within the function you can assign another value to `id`.

Comment: There's no meaningful difference between let and var in this case, since the scope of function arguments are always the entire function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Declaring variables with destructuring uses the same scope as if you'd declared ordinary variables in the same position. So if you do:

```
let {id} = {id: 42};
```

then it's a `let` binding, if you do:

```
var {id} = {id: 42};
```

then it's a `var` binding.

Function parameters are like `var` bindings, since they're scoped to the entire function and they're not `const`. They're also like `let` bindings because they're scoped to the current block, which is the entire function body.

Comment: "for a variable declared in the top-level block of a function, there's no difference between `let` and `var`": I like my wording better. `function x() { var a = b; var b = a; }` is okay; `function x() { var a = b; let b = a; }` is a `ReferenceError`. They are equivalent at the top of the function, not necessarily at top *level* of a function, because `let` doesn't hoist.

Comment: I think this is functionally true, yes, but is there anywhere I can read on an implementation level what is happening under the hood? I can't find anything on MDN.

Comment: @komali_2: Everything is in [ECMAScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/). It is a bit hard to read though if you're not used to it.

Comment: @komali_2: Specifically, look at [FunctionDeclarationInstantiation(func, argumentsList)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-functiondeclarationinstantiation).

Answer (score 1):

It will be a local variable scoped over the whole function (as all function parameters are), as in your first and second example (which are equivalent: there is no difference between `let` and `var` when at the top of the function).